# Operation not permitted when trying to set time using Tizen emulator Shell

Tags: time, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator

When trying to set time for an emulated `Samsung Gear 2s` using `Tizen` emulator's command shell, I get an **Operation not permitted** error.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Command tried:

```
sh-3.2$ **date --set="3 JAN 2016 18:00:00"**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From sdb shell you can change date/time only in root mode.**

Once the emulator is started. Right click on the emulator and select '**Shell**' from the option which will open the sdb shell in user($) mode. Please run **su** command to go to root(**#**) mode. Then run below command on the shell to change the date/time

```
sh-3.2# date --set="3 JAN 2016 18:00:00"
```

Comment: Please mark it as the answer, so that other user can find the answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

One hack could be to add a sdb client on system and run it from a regular app